# Burn CD to be used on Red Hat 5.3

Tags: linux, windows-xp, dvd-burning

I have never burned a DVD to be used on a Linux box before. If I am burning a CD using a Windows program (not built-in burning), is there anything special I need to be aware of to make sure the DVD will be able to be read on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is aware of pretty much all formats you're likely to write.  Most likely if it's a data CD / DVD you'll burn an `ISO9660` format disk with the `Joilet` extensions.  You might experience problems if you have any filenames over 64 characters long, but that's reasonably unlikely (in many cases filenames up to 103 characters work OK).

Comment: Just as a warning (for windows XP): "I burned a couple of DVDs that way, and WinXP didn't see the names correctly though it would start the files." for 103 character names.[Source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/implications-of-setting-k3b-to-use-103-character-joliet-filenames-557056/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use default settings and avoid things like overburning etc., then you should have no problems. I used my CDs burned in Windows in various programs like Nero 5.5, Ashampoo burning studio free, Infrarecorder and some newer Nero Express in various linux distributions and never had problems.